# Entity Model - Specify display properties

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have my entity models and I want to be able to specify in the entity classes properties, such as "Don't display this property", or "This property should be displayed using this string", etc. How would I do this? And is there a way to make sure these properties don't get deleted when the models are regenerated when my edmx changes?
Thanks.

Example:

```
[DisplayName="SomeColumnNameToUse"]
public String SomeModelProperty {get;set;}
```

Comment: Showing some example code with some more detail here would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1> To specify what should be displayed, in which format, it is probably a better idea to use a ViewModel to convert the data exactly as you want them to be display. Also you could modifiy the datatemplate of your User Control in the XAML file.

2>

> is there a way to make sure these properties don't get deleted when
>   the models are regenerated

You could use partial class. Keep the generated class clean, just make it partial. Then create a partial custom class. Still, it is not a good idea to be highly coupled with your low level POCO. I repeat you better use them in a ViewModel.